# R: "Error in facet_grid" - "unused argument"

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am trying to plot some data from my experiment in R using `ggplot2`, and I am trying to split the graph in two parts using `facet_grid()`.

Here is an MWE I built with the cars dataset:

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mtcars$mpg,y=mtcars$cyl)) + 
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(rows=mtcars$disp)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in facet_grid(rows = mtcars$disp) : 
  unused argument (rows = mtcars$disp)
```

I really have no idea why this is happening. I used this function before, and it worked fine. Would appreciate ideas on how to solve this.

*edit: 
I accepted the second answer, because it provides some more context, but as I see it, both are equally correct in pointing out that I need to quote the variable name. The actual error was resolved after installig R and all packages again. Now I have a new error, but that is another story. Thanks again!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't explicitly refer to `mtcars` within the `aes()` call.
Second, quote the facet argument.

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=cyl)) + 
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(rows="disp")
```

Also, consider creating a new variable that collapses `disp` into fewer values for the facet to be more meaningful & readable.

[image: not-cut]

Here's an example of four arbitrary cut points.

```
mtcars$disp_cut_4 <- cut(mtcars$disp, breaks=c(0, 200, 300, 400, 500))
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=cyl)) + 
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(rows="disp_cut_4")
```

[image: cut]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the quotes! I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. I guess something is wrong with my installation? I will try to update everything, and will post an update soon.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + 
 geom_point()+
 facet_grid(rows = "disp")
```

alternatively:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + 
 geom_point()+
 facet_grid(~disp)
```